# Какой цвет фона используется?

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование, background, figma

Всем привет. Никак не получается у меня получить такой же цвет фона как на макете. Подскажите пожалуйста что делать и как получить такой же цвет.

Вот макет: https://www.figma.com/file/tOMcpja1UEQMphG0Wtc6Tx/%5BPublished%5D%5BRU%5D-%C2%ABElite-Fire%C2%BB?node-id=0%3A1&t=NpuLZK4fuTbBYrTS-0

Цвет вроде как rgba(18, 18, 18, 0.5), но у меня совсем другой результат получается. Плюс там какой-то шум или что-то вроде того что-ли наложен.

Comment: Так фон неоднородный, как можно назвать его цвет?

Comment: @T0xee.n17 а как верстать в таком случае такой фон?

Comment: Вероятнее всего сам фон - одного цвета, засветы - уже фон блоков информации. Возможно это png картинки, или просто background-color прозрачный. В самом тёмном месте фон имеет цвет #080808, можете отталкиваться от него

Comment: @T0xee.n17 хорошо, спасибо большое!